# modulus.io #meteor 1.0.0 failed deploy '/mnt/data/2/programs/server/app/node_modules/underscore/underscore-min.js'

Tags: meteor, modulus, demeteorizer

When attempting to deploy a meteor 1.0.0 app on modulus I get an error message about a non-existing underscore-min.js.

Both demeteorizer and modulus toolbelt at the latest version.

```
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/mnt/data/2/programs/server/app/node_modules/underscore/underscore-min.js'
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:438:18)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:289:15)
    at /mnt/data/2/programs/server/boot.js:83:19
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (/mnt/data/2/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
    at /mnt/data/2/programs/server/boot.js:82:5
[2015-01-03T18:48:01.182Z] Application CRASH detected. Exit code 8.
```

Comment: are you using FSCollection? from alanning and raix?

Comment: You need to add underscore explicitly with latest meteor update, it is no longer supported